# Href insert column

Tags: html

how do I add a href to this column?

```
            <div class="col-md-6" style="height: 125px;">
            <div style="background: #ffffff;"></div>
            <div class="border rounded border-dark box" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-duration="500" style="background: #204424;margin-bottom: 30px;padding: 30px;margin-top: -10%;">
            <h3 class="text-center name" style="color: rgb(255,255,255);font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;">TEXT</h3>
            </div>
```

Comment: Check this out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a :)

Comment: Can you please send the code?

Comment: Please read this guide on how to ask in here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functionality you are attempting to implement is not clear.

If you are after creating a link for users to jump to a specific element or spot your page, you can do the following:

1. First, identify the location by adding the following id attribute to an element tag where you want users to jump.

   `id = "id_name"`

•    `id_name` is the name you create for the section.

Your code could look something like this:

```
<div id="id_name" class="col-md-6" style="height: 125px;">
            <div style="background: #ffffff;"></div>
            <div class="border rounded border-dark box" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-duration="500" style="background: #204424;margin-bottom: 30px;padding: 30px;margin-top: -10%;">
            <h3 class="text-center name" style="color: rgb(255,255,255);font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;">TEXT</h3>
            </div>
```

Note: ID"s must be unique. The browser will jump to the first occurrence if you use more than one by the same name.

2. Create the link.

- If you are linking to a location within the same document, use the following:

```
<a href="#id_name">Link Title</a>
```

- If linking to a location in a separate file, use the following:

```
<a href="file_name.html">Link Title</a>
```

- `file_name.html` is the file containing the element you would like to jump to.

If you want to create a link within the `div`, you can do the following.

1. Links are created by enclosing content within a set of opening and closing `<a>` tags.

```
<a href="destination_url">Link Name</a>
```

Where `destination_url` is a `url` that points to the location of a file on your server, or a server accessible from the internet.

Common destination url's are:

- `http` (resource accessible on the world wide web)
- `https` (a secure connection to a resource on the world wide web)
- `fax` (a fax phone number)
- `ftp` (download a resource stored on an FTP server)
- `geo` (geophysical coordinate: opens default navigation app with coordinate populated)
- `mailto` (opens users default mail client with the destination email populated)
- `tel` (opens phone app with phone number populated)
- `sms` (opens text messaging app with phone number populated)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response! 

I will make the hol div a href to another page. 
So not the text in the div, and not to the same page. 

How can i do that?

Comment: You can enclose the outermost div in a set of <a> tags.
Ex:
<a href="destination_url">
<div>
//div contents here....
</div>
</a>

Also, the code you provided is missing a closing </div> tag.